# aws s3 upload only policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

More of a check than a question.
I have created a bucket in s3 and I want to give a specific user access to upload files to a specific bucket. This is the policy I created:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "se:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:*"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybycketsname"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybycketsname/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I created a user with Programmatic access as the files are going to be sent through a script and attached only the above policy. The user need only add in one bucket: mybycketsname.
Does my policy cover the use case?

Comment: you only can test the policy by trying various operations on the bucket with that user... did you try that?

Comment: Why would you allow for everything then `["s3:*"]`?

Comment: Also you want to give the user console access as well, or only a programmatic access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest policy you would require is:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybycketsname/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This grants permission to upload (`PutObject`) files into the `mybycketsname` bucket.

They cannot do anything else (such as list the contents of the bucket or delete objects).